# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark' on emr cluster

Tags: amazon-emr

I have created an EMR cluster along with Jupyter notebook and chose Pyspark for it. When I tried to import pyspark it gave me an error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'". I have run pip install pyspark and it seems like it was installed successfully but still gives me the same error. How can this be fixed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: pls provide more details, such as how did you create the EMR cluster, through the CLI or AWS console, how did you run the `pip install pyspark`, what makes you believe it has been successfully installed?

Comment: I have created an EMR cluster through AWS console, I have also created a notebook choosing PySpark. Once I opened the notebook and ran the command: "import pyspark" I have the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'". Then I have ran `pip install pyspark` in my terminal and it says that it was sucessfully installed. I also have used PySpark on my local machine.

Comment: I guess is you installed package to a different python interpreter. Also, have you tried to install packages using the bootstrap option when you create the cluster? And if you choose the `pyspark` as interpreter, do you experience the same problem?

Comment: Make sure you use the kernel pyspark